# PHP code to round decimals up

Tags: php

I am using

```
$p1 = 66.97;

$price1  = $row['Value']*$p1;
$price1 = number_format($price1, 2, '.', '');
```

To do a simple calculation and then show the price to 2 decimal places. this works fine. I would like to round the result up to the nearest `.05`. So `18.93` would be `18.95`, `19.57` would be `19.60` etc. Any ideas on this - I am struggling. Thanks.

Comment: What would 18.92 round to? 18.90?

Comment: 18.95 evidently, round up.

Comment: @Aneri That's just an assumption, I'd rather hear it from the OP. People don't always say what they mean.

Comment: There's this really helpful website called the PHP manual! http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php It's available in all kinds of different languages and it's really helpful.

Comment: Did I mention helpful.

Comment: sorry yes 18.92 would round up to 18.95

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like:

```
$price = ceil($p1*20)/20;
```

You need to round up to `0.05`; ceil normally rounds up to `1`; so you need to multiply your number by 20 (`1/0.05 = 20`) to allow ceil do what you want, and then divide the number you came up with;

Be aware of float arithmetics, your result might really be something like 12.949999999999999999999 instead of 12.95; so you should convert it to string with `sprintf('%.2f', $price)` or `number_format` as in your example

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your answer by 100, then do a modulo division by 5. If the remainder is less than 3, subtract the remainder, else add (5 - remainder). Next, divide by 100 to get to the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function roundUpToAny($n,$x=5) {
    return round(($n+$x/2)/$x)*$x;
}

i.e.:

echo '52 rounded to the nearest 5 is ' . roundUpToAny(52,5) . '<br />';
// returns '52 rounded to the nearest 5 is 55'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$price = ceil($price1 * 20) / 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
// First, multiply by 100
$price1 = $price1 * 100;
// Then, check if remainder of division by 5 is more than zero
if (($price1 % 5) > 0) {
    // If so, substract remainder and add 5
    $price1 = $price1 - ($price1 % 5) + 5;
}
// Then, divide by 100 again
$price1 = $price1 / 100;
```